# TV Anime with a girl who had a blue "ball" on her body

Tags: story-identification, tv, manga, anime

I remember watching a couple episodes in the 90s or maybe 2000s. The main character is a girl, she has a sort of blue ball on her body, it is sets in a modern city... I think the balls could become weapons... It is the only things I remember... It's not KIBA

Comment: Maybe Squid Girl? They are more so bracelets, but the setting matches.

Comment: In what sense is the ball on her body? Balanced on her head, drawn on her tummy?